# I'm new to coding & I'm learning python and I wrote some code but there's a function that never works and the reason isn't that obvious for me

Tags: python, function

If I call this function, it never works, just like it never gets called and without errors, even tho (parameter == 'h') is True, and the help function works, and the function is called properly.
I tried everything I could think of.

Function:

```
def nav(parameter):
    if parameter == 'h':
        help(parameter)
```

Help Function:

```
def help(parameter):
    clearConsole()
    print("Help Menu")
    # other code
```

How I called it:

```
nav(userInput)
```

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: There is a builtin function `help`. Try giving it a different name.

Comment: What happens when you call it with `nav('h')`?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I was expecting the nav() function to call the help() function.

Comment: @PeterWood I'm not sure how to do it, but it's solved now, I think that I missed a symbol or mistyped a parameter, still not sure of the reason tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish :

```
def nav(parameter):
    if parameter == 'h':
        help(parameter)
    
def help(parameter):
    clearConsole()
    print("Help Menu")
    # other code

import os

def clearConsole():
    command = 'clear'
    if os.name in ('nt', 'dos'):  # If Machine is running on Windows, use cls
        command = 'cls'
    os.system(command)


user_input = input("Enter a character : ")
nav(user_input)
```

things I added :

1. user input
2. clearConsole() method

Comment: Thank you! I already had the clearConsole() function defined, but I copied and pasted this and it works somehow, I might have missed a symbol or entered a wrong parameter, not sure tho.